# Can a seaborn (distplot) yaxis be automatically rescaled?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

Can a [Seaborn distplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) be set to automatically re-scale the yaxis to capture the maximum y extent of multiple plotted datasets?

When doing batches of plots using [Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/), sometimes it is unavoidable  that data is provided without an increasing maximum frequency value. When this happens the created plot yaxis cuts off data. However, [`sns.distplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) is fine if data is provided with increasing maximum.

This can be fixed via [`Matplotlib.patches`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html) or just by calling [`ax.autoscale()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.autoscale.html)(Thanks [@ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest) for the later suggestion), but either seems "kludgey"...

Simple worked example:

```
# Import modules
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import truncnorm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(color_codes=True)

# Make some random data (credit: [@bakkal's Answer][3])
scale = 3.
range = 10
size = 100000
X = truncnorm(a=-range/scale, b=+range/scale, scale=scale).rvs(size=size)

# --- first time to show issue
# Now plot up 1st set of data (with first dataset having high Y values)
ax= sns.distplot( X*4 )
# Now plot up two more
for i in np.arange(1, 3):
    sns.distplot( X*i, ax=ax )
plt.show()
```

[image: (Issue!)]

```
# --- Second time with a "kludgey" fix
ax = sns.distplot( X*4 )
# Now plot up two more
for i in np.arange(1, 3):
    sns.distplot( X*i, ax=ax )
# Now force y axis extent to be correct
ax.autoscale()
plt.show()
```

[image: (Success!)]

```
# --- Third time with increasing max in data provided 
ax= sns.distplot( X )
# Now plot up two more
for i in np.arange(2, 4 ):
    sns.distplot( X*i, ax=ax )
plt.show()
```

[image: (success too)]

Comment: Since I cannot reproduce this behaviour in seaborn 8.1, the easiest solution may be to update your seaborn package. You may also try `ax.autoscale()`.

Comment: Thanks for the input @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. I added a [github issue](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1329) before I saw your comment and it has been fixed between in 0.8.1. Also thanks for mentioning ``ax.autoscale()``, that's better than using [patches](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html). I'll add that to the Q and credit you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an issue in [Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) (0.8.0) and a fix has been a submitted on [github](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1329).

If you also see this issue please update just Seaborn (>= [version 0.8.1](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/releases/tag/v0.8.1)).

Comment: And reload *all* libraries. Just reloading seaborn did not suffice.